# Object reference issue in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think I am doing right, but I have `"Object reference not set to an instance"` error.

I have `GolfDrive GameObject`. Then `Golf_drive2` animation is put under it. As shown in the first image.

[image]

Then I have a variable `currentObject` in my script and set `Golf_drive2` to control the animation. As shown in the second image.

[image]

When I tried to access the animation as follow

```
var frame = currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>()[currentObj.name].time;
```

I have `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`.
What could be wrong?

EDIT:
I changed as

```
var frame = 1.2f;
if (currentObj != null)
    frame = currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>()[currentObj.name].time;
```

That means currentObj is not null. Then still have the same error.

EDIT 2:
I tested the animation as

```
Animation n = currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>();
if (n == null)
   Debug.Log("I AM NULL");
```

Nothing is printed, so animation is not null.

Comment: Either the currentObj is null or the value of currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>()[currentObj.name] could be null.

Comment: Which game object has the animation component?

Comment: @Steve Golf_drive2

Comment: @KarthikAMR no I can do Debug.Log(currentObj.name) and I see "Golf_drive2"

Comment: @batuman can you check the value of currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>()[currentObj.name] ?

Comment: @batuman does `Golf_drive2` have multiple animation components then?

Comment: @Steve no only one. mixamo.com

Comment: @KarthikAMR I did Debug.Log("frame " + frame);,nothing come out.

Comment: I changed as shown in EDIT, but still have error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled not duplicate, that is pure C#. Now I have initialized in the inspectore.

Comment: @batuman why are you using an array accessor (the square brackets)? I'm new to Unity but have a lot of experience in C#, but I can't work out why you need to do that.

Comment: @Steve i see, let me check

Comment: @batuman are you trying to access the [current time of the Animation State](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-time.html)? Make sure the animation component has a `Golf_drive2` state that it can access.

Comment: @Steve thanks let me check that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps `currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>()` returns null, or somewhere in the `GetComponent` you get the exception and it bubbles...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have updated in EDIT2. thanks

Comment: Thanks now solved. Somehow I need to assign the name of the animation file as float frame = currentObj.GetComponent<Animation>()["mixamo.com"].time;